# How to specify the address of ResourceManager to bin/yarn-session.sh?

Tags: hadoop, apache-flink, hadoop-yarn

I am a newbie in Flink.
I'm confused about how to specify the address of ResourceManager when run `bin/yarn-session.sh`?

Answer (score 0):

When starting a Flink Yarn session via `bin/yarn-session.sh` then it will create a `.yarn-properties-USER` file in your tmp directory. This file will contain the connection information for the Flink cluster. When trying to submit a job via `bin/flink run <JOB_JAR>`, the client will use the connection information from this file.